# Is Delphi Firemonkey's DoRealign implemented correctly?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

This is the original TControl.DoRealign :

```
procedure TControl.DoRealign;
begin
  if not FNeedAlign then
    Exit;
  AlignObjects(Self, FPadding, FSize.Width, FSize.Height, FLastWidth, FLastHeight, FDisableAlign);
end;
```

but I think it should be written like

```
procedure TControl.DoRealign;
var aSize: TpointF;
begin
  aSise := Size.Size;

  if not FNeedAlign then
    Exit;
  AlignObjects(Self, FPadding, FSize.Width, FSize.Height, FLastWidth, FLastHeight, FDisableAlign);

  if not aSize.EqualsTo(Size.Size) then DoRealign;
end;
```

because often we assign some event to some control onresize (like TText with autosize=True) to resize their parentcontrols to the same size as them. But in this way the problem is that if we resize the parentcontrol during it's dorealign process then it will not call again dorealign

Did i get it well or did i miss something ? or is their a better way to make a parent control to fit the size of it's childreen by assigning onresize to them ?

Comment: You want to introduce (possibly infinite) recursion? I don't think that would be a good idea. But you can implement it in your own copy (be sure to rename it, this is a license requirement) and see how it works out. And library code should **never** assign to properties (events) of its own.

Comment: Since the above won't compile, I guess you didn't try this yet?